# implement type 4 jdbc driver in DB2

Tags: servlets, jdbc, db2

In my project I'm using few configurations in context.xml and servlet.xml, where I'm setting

```
<ResourceLink 
     global="jdbc/mydatasource" 
     name="jdbc/mydatasource" 
     type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<Resource 
     name="jdbc/mydatasource"
     auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username=" DATABASE_USERNAME"
     password=" DATABASE_PASSWORD"
     driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
     url="jdbc:db2://IP:port/DBname" />
```

and using it in my servlet by including it through

```
 datasource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydatasource");
```

But I want to know what type of driver (type 2, 4, etc). I've imported db2jcc.jar in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for **DB2 type 4 driver** gives me this page of IBM: [Understand the DB2 UDB JDBC Universal Driver](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0512kokkat/) (from 2005). Reading this makes clear that `db2jcc.jar` is the universal driver, which is both a Type 2 and a Type 4 driver. What you use depends on the JDBC url you specify:

For Type 4:

- jdbc:db2//server:port/database
- jdbc:db2//server/database

For Type 2:

- jdbc:db2:database

Be aware that - according to this site - you will also need `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` on your classpath to get the Type 4 driver to work.

Comment: @Mark-I've used `jdbc:db2//server:port/database` statement in my code but the customer is saying t use it like `jdbc:db2//port/database` this, to make it Type 4, i've not included db2jcc_license_cu.jar file also, bcoz no where it asked me for that in the code...

Comment: @Ars I don't use DB2 myself, but `jdbc:db2//port/database` doesn't make sense unless 1) the driver supports leaving out the hostname (which is unlikely) and 2) the database is running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Java has the [`DatabaseMetaData` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), which may have the information you are looking for.  I'm not a Java person, but [`getDriverMajorVersion()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDriverMajorVersion%28%29) may return what you're looking for.

Comment: That will simply return the major version of the driver, not the JDBC Type.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incorrect actually:

For Type4:

- jdbc:db2://server:port/database
- jdbc:db2://server/database

Missing another colon.