# Java - DB2 Connection Issue

Tags: java, db2

This is my Class trying to connect Db2:

```
package Test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Db2Connection {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;
    String driverName = "COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver";
    String db2ConnectString = "jdbc:db2:DB2XAT33;UID=G37RSF4;PWD=HOT22RST";
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db2ConnectString);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException Message --       "+      e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("SQLException Message -- " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("UnsatisfiedLinkError Message -- " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();            
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("General Exception Message --        "                  +                            e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

when i run this i am getting below Exception:

```
       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SQLAllocEnv
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.<init>(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName1(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:142)
```

I have Db2.zip in Folder "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\". And i added Db2.zip and ojdbc.jar to my Package via JavaBuildpath.

Comment: Does that driver need a native library?

Answer (score 1):

Check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH shell environment variable; it needs to contain the directory where db2's libraries are. Google for "websphere db2 ld_library_path" without the quotes.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH shell environment variable -- Will this be specific to Server? Where this file will be?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the type 2 (the so called "app") driver, which 1) requires that you install at least the runtime client with native CLI/ODBC libraries and 2) is deprecated.

Consider using the type 4 ("jcc") driver, which is pure Java. More information can be found here: [implement type 4 jdbc driver in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526592/implement-type-4-jdbc-driver-in-db2)